# Unable to export recent logs from Microsoft graph API in identity protection

Tags: powershell, api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, identity

I have this weird issue when I try to get data from Identity protection by using MS graphs API, I only get two months ago data and not recent ones, what could be the issue here?

I'm using PowerShell to extract the data

Comment: What is the PowerShell coammnd-let or the Graph API endpoint you are using to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figure out the mistake I'm doing in here, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityProtection/riskDetections is not only a single output
once I add a while loop until '@Odata.NextLink' is not null it gives me the full range